# Efficiently drawing lines using python

Tags: python, graphics, vector-graphics

I am trying to work out an efficient way of drawing line patterns on a screen using python.

A while ago I cobbled together some code that could drive a LAser Spirograph. Which is basically 3 circles each rotating around a moving point of the circumference of each other. This produces a series of point that trace out various patterns depending on the relative speeds each of the circles are spinning.

So now i have a long list of x,y cord that I want to plot as a single line, is there a function in python (currently playing with Pygames) that will take a series of points and conect them with a smooth curved line.

for example say i have a few hundred point that describe the pattern in this [link](http://cdn.instructables.com/FLA/AG03/G9NH9DK4/FLAAG03G9NH9DK4.MEDIUM.jpg), is there a "simple" way in Python to render he full pattern to screen. I am assuming this would be faster than trying to plot each of several thousand points to get the appearance of a line.

EDIT

I have been assuming that there would be a faster way to draw say a semi circle to the screen by passing a function the start and end point plus the radius. rather than calculate 2,000 points on the curve and plotting them separately either as points or short straight lines. I also am assuming its quicker to plot a straight line 100 points long than outputting the same line as separate points?

Comment: [**`pygame.draw.lines`**](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.lines)

Comment: Hi, as I understood it that draws a series of lines between the points not a smooth continues one. For example three points can be joined with two straight lints and form an angel, or one smooth curve. I want the curve.

Comment: You'd need to define the tangents and weight of the endpoints. What path should the curve follow otherwise?

Comment: You don't want the curve.  You want to sample the curve with a frequency sufficient to fool perception

Comment: Tangent is possible, and each point of the line needs to be passed through exactly.

Comment: See [BezierCurve](http://pygame.org/wiki/BezierCurve) on the [PyGame Wiki](http://pygame.org/wiki/index).

Comment: gboffi, well I am not sure, a full on plot in small enough sample points would be many thousands of points. the lines are based on mathmatical formula so in theory, getting start mid and tangent of each should be easy.  Question is is it quicker to cacualte and 1000,s of points or hundreds of lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer* This is not an answer

---

To expand on my comment above

> You don't want the curve. You want to sample the curve with a frequency sufficient to fool perception

have a look at the effects of denser vs coarser sampling on the perception of what is drawn on a screen

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, np.pi*3, 301)
x = np.sin(t)
```

each of the points `(t[i], x[i])` represent a point, here a pont in a sine curve, in your application a more complex curve, so let's plot these points using a different sampling step, to see if the sampling rate has an effect on your perception of what is drawn...

```
for step in (1, 25, 50):
    plt.plot(t[::step], x[::step], label='step=%d'%step)
#                ^^^^       ^^^^             
plt.ylim((-1.05, 1.05))
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

that gives me

[image]

I dare say, with a sufficiently high sampling rate what is drawn *looks* like a curve, even if  it is a sequence of straight segments (as it's apparent when you look at the other two istances of `t` vs `x`).

In other comments, you were told which `pygames` function you can use to do your deed.

Comment: hi, cheers for putting it out in full, My consern is trying to pick the right sampling rate, for some parts of the curve "0.75-1.25" the curve is almost straight. while from 1.25 - 1.75 a straight line would be very evidently deviating from the curve. I might well revert to this, but will have a look a bezier curves to.

Comment: When the sine is near the maximum the curvature too has its maximum values, otoh when the sine crosses a zero the curvature is near to zero, hence the sine curve is pretty close to a straight line. And equisampling WORKS in both regions. At any rate I won't try further to convince you because I feel I won't convince you. Ciao